# Add repetitions to a column in dataframe using a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello simple R question but what would be the best way to have each item in `List_A` to repeat every item in `List_B` once in a data.frame.

```
List_A = c("a","b","c")
List_B = c("one","oneb","two","twoa","three","threea")
```

Desired Output:

```
data.frame(List_A = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c",,"c","c","c"),
List_B = c("one","oneb","two","twob","three","threeb","one","oneb","two","twob","three","threeb","one","oneb","two","twob","three","threeb"))
```

Comment: `expand.grid(List_A=List_A, List_B=List_B)`

Comment: @HubertL worked perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following @HubertL suggestion I was able to get the dataframe with the repeated `List_B`.

```
expand.grid(List_A=List_A, List_B=List_B)
```